# Is there a way to automate / script video editing with python?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, image-editing

I do have the problem that I have to generate a daily video file for an information screen.

I need to be able to create a video with preferably a python script that goes over all images in a directory and display each image for 10 seconds while scrolling corresponding text next to it and then display the next image. I might also have to have the ability to add a sound file or background music in the future.

I have looked at **ffmpeg** and it has some ability to do what I want but I thought there might be a better way or tool I could use. Since **ffmpeg** takes a lot of steps and its really hacky.

I am able to code the python myself I just need some API or library to handle the video processing.

Not 100% this is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution which i'm going to evaluate now.

This looks promising as its basically a python wrapper for ffmpeg and has a lot of example code:

https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html